# Rsyslog forward logs cannot connect Permission Denied

Tags: centos, syslog, selinux, syslogd

Have configured Rsyslog to ship logs to a remote location through an SSH tunnel.

However rsyslog complains with "Permission denied":

```
rsyslogd[28412]: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:10601: Permission denied [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
```

The server is CentOS Stream 8

The tunnel is verified to be up - `ss -lntp` - and I'm able to send through it with i.e. `echo test | nc 127.0.0.1 601`, and the test shows up at the remote.

The tunnel is kept up by `autossh` running as an unprivileged user, thus the local port must be unprivileged (or you get `bind [127.0.0.1]:601: Permission denied` when setting up the tunnel).

Forwarding is done through the Rsyslog `omfwd` Forwarding Output Module

```
# /etc/rsyslog.d/00-forward.conf
# Forward to remote server through an ssh tunnel / autossh
*.info action(type="omfwd"
         queue.Type="LinkedList"
         queue.Filename="forward_queue_1"
         queue.MaxDiskSpace="3m"
         queue.SaveOnshutdown="on"
         action.ResumeRetryCount="-1"
         target="127.0.0.1" port="10601" protocol="tcp"
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Rsyslog runs as root, so you should not normally get a permission denied.

Diving into `/var/log/messages` (or `/var/log/syslog` if on i.e. Ubuntu) should provide some clues.

```
grep 10601 /var/log/messages  # search for the port number
... setroubleshoot[29284]: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/rsyslogd from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 10601. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 005c986c-e0f9-481a-b3c6-0b45a9698ccd
... setroubleshoot[31103]: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/rsyslogd from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 10601.#012#012*****  Plugin connect_ports (92.2 confidence) suggests   *********************#012#012If you want to allow /usr/sbin/rsyslogd to connect to network port 10601#012Then you need to modify the port type.#012Do#012# semanage port -a -t PORT_TYPE -p tcp 10601#012    where PORT_TYPE is one of the following: dns_port_t, dnssec_port_t, http_port_t, kerberos_port_t, mysqld_port_t, ocsp_port_t, postgresql_port_t, rsh_port_t, syslog_tls_port_t, syslogd_port_t, wap_wsp_port_t.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.83 confidence) suggests   ******************#012#012If you want to
```

**And there it is:**

rsyslog has been configured to send to a non standard port and [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is denying it.

The sollution - if you keep the non-standard port - is to allow the port in SElinux.

Get details from `sealert -l 005c986c-e0f9-481a-b3c6-0b45a9698ccd` - the UUID is unique to you of course.

```
If you want to allow /usr/sbin/rsyslogd to connect to network port 10601
Then you need to modify the port type.
Do
# semanage port -a -t PORT_TYPE -p tcp 10601
    where PORT_TYPE is one of the following: dns_port_t, dnssec_port_t, http_port_t, kerberos_port_t, mysqld_port_t, ocsp_port_t, postgresql_port_t, rsh_port_t, syslog_tls_port_t, syslogd_port_t, wap_wsp_port_t.
```

I declare that my port is a `syslogd_port_t`

```bash
semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp 10601

# Restart rsyslog for good measure
systemctl restart rsyslog  # or "pkill -HUP rsyslog"
```

Logs are now sent.